# Trying to build a BST Tree from scratch in C

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build a BST from scratch on my own for an assignment, and all I have is a few months experience in C. Got stuck on adding new nodes, apparently the Root is being replaced every time. Here are a few snippets.

Structure:

```
typedef struct node
{ 
    int Num;
    struct node * left;     /* Points to the left child*/
    struct node * right;    /*Points to the right child*/
    struct node *parent;

}Node;

typedef struct tree
{   
    Node * root; /*Points to the root*/
    int height;
}Tree;
```

Functions:

```
void AddNode(int num, Tree * tree){
    Node NewNode;
    NewNode.Num=num;
    NewNode.left=NULL;
    NewNode.right=NULL;
    NewNode.parent=NULL;

    Compare(tree,&NewNode,tree->root);
}

void Compare(Tree * tree,Node * newNode,Node * oldNode)
{
    if (oldNode == NULL)
        {
            oldNode=newNode;
            printf("hi1");
        }
    else if (newNode->Num<oldNode->Num)
        {
        printf("hi2");
            if (oldNode->left==NULL)
                {
                    oldNode->left=newNode;
                    oldNode->left->parent=oldNode;
                }
            else
                Compare(tree,newNode,oldNode->left);
        }
    else if (newNode->Num>oldNode->Num)
        {
            printf("hi3");
            if (oldNode->right==NULL)
                {
                    oldNode->right=newNode;
                    oldNode->right->parent=oldNode;
                }
            else
                Compare(tree,newNode,oldNode->right);
        }
}
```

I have an array with some numbers. In the beginning I initialized the tree. the printfs are there for debugging. the output is:

```
Tree Initialized
hi1hi1hi1hi1
```

which must mean that the root is being replaced every time. I tried taking away

```
if (oldNode == NULL)
            {
                oldNode=newNode;
                printf("hi1");
            }
```

and made the root as array[0] before calling the AddNode method, however the program stops executing. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not destroy a question by removing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A principal problem is in `AddNode()`:

```
void AddNode(int num, Tree * tree)
{
    Node NewNode;
    NewNode.Num=num;
    NewNode.left=NULL;
    NewNode.right=NULL;
    NewNode.parent=NULL;
    Compare(tree,&NewNode,tree->root);
}
```

When you return from the function, the storage for `NewNode` is reused on the next call.  You need to dynamically allocate the new node:

```
void AddNode(int num, Tree * tree)
{
    Node *NewNode = malloc(sizeof(*NewNode));
    if (NewNode == 0)
        abort();
    NewNode->Num=num;
    NewNode->left=NULL;
    NewNode->right=NULL;
    NewNode->parent=NULL;
    Compare(tree, NewNode, tree->root);
}
```

There are other problems too — still working on those.  It would help if you showed your code for (a) populating the BST and (b) for printing the contents of the BST and (c) releasing the storage used by the BST.  If you don't have item (b), you can't debug your own structures.

#### An SSCCE

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{ 
    int Num;
    struct node *left;     /* Points to the left child */
    struct node *right;    /* Points to the right child */
    struct node *parent;
} Node;

typedef struct tree
{   
    Node *root;
    int   height;
} Tree;

static void Compare(Node *newNode, Node **oldNode)
{
    if (*oldNode == NULL)
    {
        *oldNode = newNode;
        printf("hi1\n");
    }
    else if (newNode->Num < (*oldNode)->Num)
    {
        printf("hi2\n");
        if ((*oldNode)->left==NULL)
        {
            (*oldNode)->left=newNode;
            (*oldNode)->left->parent = *oldNode;
        }
        else
            Compare(newNode, &(*oldNode)->left);
    }
    else if (newNode->Num > (*oldNode)->Num)
    {
        printf("hi3\n");
        if ((*oldNode)->right==NULL)
        {
            (*oldNode)->right=newNode;
            (*oldNode)->right->parent = *oldNode;
        }
        else
            Compare(newNode, &(*oldNode)->right);
    }
} 

static void AddNode(int num, Tree *tree)
{
    assert(tree != 0);
    Node *NewNode = malloc(sizeof(*NewNode));
    if (NewNode == 0)
        abort();
    NewNode->Num    = num;
    NewNode->left   = NULL;
    NewNode->right  = NULL;
    NewNode->parent = NULL;
    Compare(NewNode, &tree->root);
}

static void DumpNode(const Node *node)
{
    assert(node != 0);
    printf("Number: %4d - Node: 0x%.9" PRIXPTR " (parent 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ", left 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ", right 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ")\n",
            node->Num, (uintptr_t)node, (uintptr_t)node->parent, (uintptr_t)node->left, (uintptr_t)node->right);
    if (node->left != 0)
        DumpNode(node->left);
    if (node->right != 0)
        DumpNode(node->right);
}

static void DumpTree(const char *tag, const Tree *tree)
{
    assert(tag != 0 && tree != 0);
    printf("BST Dump: %s\n", tag);

    printf("Tree: 0x%.9" PRIXPTR " (root 0x%.9" PRIXPTR ", height %d)\n",
           (uintptr_t)tree, (uintptr_t)tree->root, tree->height);
    if (tree->root != 0)
        DumpNode(tree->root);
}

static void FreeNode(Node *node)
{
    assert(node != 0);
    if (node->left != 0)
    {
        FreeNode(node->left);
        node->left = 0;
    }
    if (node->right != 0)
    {
        FreeNode(node->right);
        node->right = 0;
    }
    node->parent = 0;
    node->Num    = 0;
    free(node);
}


static void FreeTree(Tree *tree)
{
    assert(tree != 0);
    if (tree->root != 0)
        FreeNode(tree->root);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[32];
    int list[] = { 19, 7, 12, 15, 21, 8, 16, 1, 3, 5 };
    enum { LIST_SIZE = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]) };

    Tree tree = { 0, 0 };

    DumpTree(buffer, &tree);

    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    {
        AddNode(list[i], &tree);
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "After %2d: value %2d", i, list[i]);
        DumpTree(buffer, &tree);
    }

    FreeTree(&tree);
    return 0;
}
```

The main changes are that the `Compare()` function does not need the `tree` argument, and does need the `Node **oldNode` argument.  There are consequential changes in the rest of `Compare()`.  The code in `AddNode()` is almost as originally suggested; the difference is in the call to `Compare()`, of course.

The `DumpTree()` and `FreeTree()` functions are added.  The `0x%.9X` formats are needed for uniformity on my 64-bit machine, where the heap addresses are at 0x100000000 and above.  With those in place and the simple `main()`, the output I got running with `valgrind` was:

```
==48994== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==48994== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==48994== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==48994== Command: ./bst
==48994== 
==48994== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==48994==    at 0xE567: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:407)
==48994==    by 0x1778C2: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==48994==    by 0x17618D: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==48994==    by 0x17F2CF: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==48994==    by 0x100001AFE: main (bst.c:78)
==48994== 
BST Dump: 
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x000000000, height 0)
hi1
BST Dump: After  0: value 19
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
BST Dump: After  1: value  7
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x000000000)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
hi3
BST Dump: After  2: value 12
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x000000000)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009230)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
hi3
hi3
BST Dump: After  3: value 15
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x000000000)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009230)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009290)
Number:   15 - Node: 0x100009290 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi3
BST Dump: After  4: value 21
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x1000092F0)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009230)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009290)
Number:   15 - Node: 0x100009290 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   21 - Node: 0x1000092F0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
hi3
hi2
BST Dump: After  5: value  8
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x1000092F0)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009230)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x100009350, right 0x100009290)
Number:    8 - Node: 0x100009350 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   15 - Node: 0x100009290 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   21 - Node: 0x1000092F0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
hi3
hi3
hi3
BST Dump: After  6: value 16
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x1000092F0)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009230)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x100009350, right 0x100009290)
Number:    8 - Node: 0x100009350 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   15 - Node: 0x100009290 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x1000093B0)
Number:   16 - Node: 0x1000093B0 (parent 0x100009290, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   21 - Node: 0x1000092F0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
hi2
BST Dump: After  7: value  1
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x1000092F0)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x100009410, right 0x100009230)
Number:    1 - Node: 0x100009410 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x100009350, right 0x100009290)
Number:    8 - Node: 0x100009350 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   15 - Node: 0x100009290 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x1000093B0)
Number:   16 - Node: 0x1000093B0 (parent 0x100009290, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   21 - Node: 0x1000092F0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
hi2
hi3
BST Dump: After  8: value  3
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x1000092F0)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x100009410, right 0x100009230)
Number:    1 - Node: 0x100009410 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009470)
Number:    3 - Node: 0x100009470 (parent 0x100009410, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x100009350, right 0x100009290)
Number:    8 - Node: 0x100009350 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   15 - Node: 0x100009290 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x1000093B0)
Number:   16 - Node: 0x1000093B0 (parent 0x100009290, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   21 - Node: 0x1000092F0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
hi2
hi2
hi3
hi3
BST Dump: After  9: value  5
Tree: 0x7FFF5FBFF410 (root 0x100009170, height 0)
Number:   19 - Node: 0x100009170 (parent 0x000000000, left 0x1000091D0, right 0x1000092F0)
Number:    7 - Node: 0x1000091D0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x100009410, right 0x100009230)
Number:    1 - Node: 0x100009410 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x000000000, right 0x100009470)
Number:    3 - Node: 0x100009470 (parent 0x100009410, left 0x000000000, right 0x1000094D0)
Number:    5 - Node: 0x1000094D0 (parent 0x100009470, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   12 - Node: 0x100009230 (parent 0x1000091D0, left 0x100009350, right 0x100009290)
Number:    8 - Node: 0x100009350 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   15 - Node: 0x100009290 (parent 0x100009230, left 0x000000000, right 0x1000093B0)
Number:   16 - Node: 0x1000093B0 (parent 0x100009290, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
Number:   21 - Node: 0x1000092F0 (parent 0x100009170, left 0x000000000, right 0x000000000)
==48994== 
==48994== HEAP SUMMARY:
==48994==     in use at exit: 18,500 bytes in 33 blocks
==48994==   total heap usage: 43 allocs, 10 frees, 18,820 bytes allocated
==48994== 
==48994== LEAK SUMMARY:
==48994==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==48994==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==48994==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==48994==    still reachable: 18,500 bytes in 33 blocks
==48994==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==48994== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==48994== 
==48994== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==48994== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==48994== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The 33 allocations still in use are completely normal on this machine (Mac OS X 10.7.5, Valgrind 3.7.1).  They occur in functions invoked before `main()` is called.

Apart from systematic changes in `Compare()` and the dynamic allocation in `AddNode()`, the code was good to go.

Comment: for now all I did was a for loop which goes through an array of numbers, and on each loop it calls AddNode(array[i], &tree)

Comment: Yes — item (b) is a very powerful tool.  I normally write a function `void dump_tree(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Tree *tree)` for each non-trivial data structure.  The file pointer means it can write to standard output or standard error; the tag identifies which call to `dump_tree()` is operative, and (obviously) the tree argument is the structure to be printed.  Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I could see is in your code

```
void AddNode(int num, Tree * tree){
    Node NewNode;
    NewNode.Num=num;
    NewNode.left=NULL;
    NewNode.right=NULL;
    NewNode.parent=NULL;

    Compare(tree,&NewNode,tree->root);
}
```

You are declaring a newNode as simple local variable, so soon as you go out of AddNode function (after calling compare), the variable newNode goes out of scope and it's value is lost.

What you could try is instead use pointers, assign the space using malloc and then add the new nods

Comment: I've done the malloc part now, but it is still giving me the same result